# How do I set the default window size in vim?

Tags: windows, vim

When I right click on a file and open it in Vim, the default window size is too small. How can I change the settings so that the default window size is bigger?

I'm running Vim 7.3.46 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can set the `'lines'` and `'columns'` options in ~/.gvimrc (~/_gvimrc on Windows). E.g:

```
:set lines=35 columns=150
```

I don't recommend you do this in your vimrc, because setting those options in console Vim can have odd effects, if it works at all; the gvimrc is only loaded when gVim is started.

Comment: Might also want to make it a part of a GUIEnter autocmd.
See also `:h GUIEnter`.

Answer (score 18):

[This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size) suggests adding the following to _vimrc for avoiding problems with console Vim:

```
if has("gui_running")
  " GUI is running or is about to start.
  " Maximize gvim window.
  set lines=999 columns=999
else
  " This is console Vim.
  if exists("+lines")
    set lines=50
  endif
  if exists("+columns")
    set columns=100
  endif
endif
```

Also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/594838/612253) looks at how to remember the previous session's window size.